# Binomial proportion test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, proportion

I'm really confused about a basic test for a binomial proportion. Specifically, the p-value. If $n=20$ with $y=17$ successes, I want the p-value for $H_0: \pi\leq 0.7$ vs. $H_A: \pi > 0.7$. I've seen others say the way to evaluate the p-value is to take the binomial distribution with $n=20$ and $\pi=0.7$, and evaluate $$P(Y=17)+P(Y=18)+P(Y=19)+P(Y=20)=0.1071$$

But how is this correct? The null hypothesis doesn't just include $\pi=0.7$, but also any real number between 0 and 0.7, so shouldn't you also add the probabilities of observing $y \in (17,18,19,20)$ when $\pi<0.7$ ?

Comment: $P_\pi(Y\ge 17)$ is an increasing function of $\pi$ and so under the hypothesis $\pi \le 0.7$ is maximised when $\pi =0.7$

Comment: @Henry Thank you! I hadn't thought of it that way before

Comment: @Henry: Can you make that a formal answer?

Answer (score 0):

*Requested from comment:*

$P_\pi(Y \ge 17)$ is an increasing function of $\pi$ and so, under the hypothesis $\pi \le 0.7$, is maximised when $\pi =0.7$.

[image: P_\pi(Y \ge 17)]